# MacOS MongoDB IDE

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB and have been working with Oracle and SQL Server that have some easy to install and easy to use IDE. I know that Mongo already have some for windows, but is there any MongoDB IDE for MacOS?

Comment: MongoDB IDE? If you mean mongodb gui, maybe [Robomongo](http://www.robomongo.org/) is a good choice.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/fb5dgg/the-best-mongodb-gui-for-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) is pretty good. Although their shell version is a little behind. Its ok for querying and stuff not so great for admin tasks like adding/managing users.